# SQL zero-to-many column comparison

Tags: sql

Say I have two columns in a table, a and b.  For each value of a, there can be zero-to-many values of b.  If the columns are sorted by a, then by b, what is the most efficient way to mark the first value of b which is greater than the corresponding value of a in a new third column?  See simplified example below.

Initial Table

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 |
| 10 | 10 |
| 10 | 11 |
| 10 | 14 |
| 20 | 22 |
| 20 | 25 |
| 30 | 25 |
| 30 | 28 |

Desired Modified Table

| a | b | first_greater |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 | 0 |
| 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 10 | 11 | 1 |
| 10 | 14 | 0 |
| 20 | 22 | 1 |
| 20 | 25 | 0 |
| 30 | 25 | 0 |
| 30 | 28 | 0 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't suggest a specific RDBMS but I would think the following is not too inneficient, using a simple `window function` and conditional `case`.

```
select a, b,
    case when b > a
      and Row_Number() 
         over (partition by a, case when b > a then 1 end order by b)=1
     then 1 else 0 
   end as first_greater
from t
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  The ability to use a case clause inside the partition by clause for the window function was not something I had considered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another method uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when b > a and
                  lag(b, 1, a) over (partition by a order by b) <= a
             then 1 else 0
        end) as first_greater
from t;
```

In a database that supports boolean expressions, you don't need any `case` at all:

```
select t.*,
       (b > a and
        lag(b, 1, a) over (partition by a order by b) <= a
       ) as first_greater
from t;
```